# jQuery .closest default context

Tags: jquery, jquery-context

The documentation for jquery's `closest` says the following:

> .closest( selector [, context ] ) 
>   ... 
>   context 
>  *Type: Element* 
>  A DOM
>   element within which a matching element may be found. **If no context is
>   passed in then the context of the jQuery set will be used instead.**

As I understand it, the bolded text means that the two statements should be equivalent:

```
set.closest("a");

set.closest("a", set.context);
```

where `set` is some jquery set.

**However**, this does not seem to be the case:

```js
var context = $("#inner")[0];
var set = $("#el", context);

// the set's context is correctly the "inner" element
set.text("context: " + set.context.id);

// if the set's context is used, this closest should match nothing, but it matches and sets the color
set.closest("#outer").css("color", "red");

// with the context explicitly set, the "outer" is not found and no background color is set
set.closest("#outer", set.context).css("background-color", "blue");
```

```css
#outer{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when no context is explicitly set, the set's context does not seem to be used as the `#outer` element is found by `closest`.  When explicitly set, the `#outer` is correctly not found.

Is the documentation just incorrect or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess the documentation is wrong. It doesn't look like the context of the jQuery set is used if the context isn't specified.

Comment: Why you did it like `var set = $("#el", context);` ? As per doc reading what I am getting is, `closest()` try to match the `selector` expression up the ancestor chains, till it finds a match. Now the second argument the method `closest()` is just to give it the a limit till that point it will keep hunting for a match. And if no second argument it will be decided by the Jquery where `body` might be the last parent.

Comment: So your code looks like doesn't the proper example to go against the Jquery doc.

Comment: It's somewhat confusing because jQuery's `closest()` doesn't always use the context, it uses a regex to determine if a context is needed, like this `/^[\x20\t\r\n\f]*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(?:\([\x20\t\r\n\f]*((?:-\d)?\d*)[\x20\t\r\n\f]*\)|)(?=[^-]|$)/i`, so just changing it to `set.closest("#outer:first")` makes it use the context, and no longer match the element, while `$('#el').closest("#outer:first")` still matches the element like it should.

Comment: I would prefer using `parents( selector )` for parent element and in your code simply use id selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly a bug, and not how it was intended to work.

The source for `closest()` is

```
function (selectors, context) {
    var cur, 
        i = 0,
        l = this.length,
        matched = [],
        pos = rneedsContext.test(selectors) || typeof selectors !== "string" 
           ? 
           jQuery(selectors, context || this.context) 
           : 
           0;

    for (; i < l; i++) {
        for (cur = this[i]; cur && cur !== context; cur = cur.parentNode) {
            // Always skip document fragments
            if (cur.nodeType < 11 && (pos ? pos.index(cur) > -1 :

            // Don't pass non-elements to Sizzle
            cur.nodeType === 1 && jQuery.find.matchesSelector(cur, selectors))) {

                matched.push(cur);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return this.pushStack(matched.length > 1 ? jQuery.unique(matched) : matched);
}
```

What's notable is the way `pos` is defined, it's the collection to be searched for a closest parent element, and `rneedsContext` is the regex

```
/^[\x20\t\r\n\f]*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(?:\([\x20\t\r\n\f]*((?:-\d)?\d*)[\x20\t\r\n\f]*\)|)(?=[^-]|$)/i
```

If the passed in selector doesn't match that regex, no context is used whatsoever, `pos` would equal `0`, and the check for `cur` in that collection is just skipped all together, which seems mighty strange.

A quick test shows

```
var reg = /^[\x20\t\r\n\f]*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(?:\([\x20\t\r\n\f]*((?:-\d)?\d*)[\x20\t\r\n\f]*\)|)(?=[^-]|$)/i;

reg.test('#outer');       // false, no context used
reg.test('#outer:first'); // true, context used
reg.test('#outer:eq(0)'); // true, context used
```

So if you add a pseudo selector, it suddenly uses the context ?

I doubt this is what was intended, and it seems like a strange thing to do, and it surely doesn't do what the documentation says it should do.

Comment: _"The source for closest() is"_ Which version is source at post ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580013/jquery-closest-default-context/34580530#comment56906623_34580530

Comment: @guest271314 - that's from 1.11.2, but it's the same for all somewhat current versions

Comment: Tried both jsfiddles ? Issue appear to have been addressed at lastest ? Though `.text()` not set ? Or, is jsfiddle not loading latest ? Using jQuery object for `DOM` element sets `background-color` `set.closest("#outer", $(set.context)).css("background-color", "blue");`

Comment: Looking at the release notes for 2.1.4 there's no changes to `closest`, and looking at the source for 2.1.3 `closest`, and specifically the `pos` variable, is defined the same way as in the last ten versions of jQuery. Testing with 2.1.4 in jsFiddle seems to still have the same issues as well, so I think this is a bug, hats of to James for finding it, it is a strange one.

Comment: Why does using jQuery object set `background-color` https://jsfiddle.net/qeb26cox/  ?

Comment: Thanks adeneo, I had a really quick look at the source last night but hadn't gotten to the point of looking at what `rneedsContext` was actually doing.  Now I'm curious what they're actually trying to do there.  I might skim the overall jquery source to see where else they use it to see why it's needed.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - it sure seems strange that they use a regex like that to determine wether or not to use context, it surely can't be intended that if you add pseudoselectors like `;eq()`, `:first` etc. it suddenly works as documented, someone did something strange, and noone has spotted it in years ?

Comment: The only thing I could figure, is that it would probably be even stranger if `closest()` used the context from the passed in collection (the original context), as that would seem strange to most people when they do `$('#inner', '#outer').closest('body')` and find nothing, because the search is suddenly limited to `#outer`.

Comment: @adeneo actually, looking at it, the use of context is actually in the loop condition whereas `pos` is doing something else entirely.  It seems like some additional check is needed when that regex matches (and maybe rightfully so) but that the loop condition is the actual bug

Comment: Seems almost like `matchesSelector` doesn't work for these matched by the regex so it gets the set first and checks if it is contained within.  If it doesn't match the regex then it uses `matchesSelector`.

Comment: I think that if `pos` is **not** `0`, or in other words if `pos` is a jQuery collection, it uses `pos.index(cur) > -1` to determine wether or not to push the element to the array. Of course, that checks to see if `cur` is inside `pos`, like you'd expect when passing in context. If `pos` is **not** a jQuery collection, but `0`, the regex test failed, and the condition checks that `cur` is an element, and that it matches the selector passed to `closest()`, before adding `cur` to the array, all done without any checks for context. I think the condition works, as long as `pos` is set correctly.

Comment: It looks like `matchesSelector` tries to use the browser's native `matches`.  Of course `matches` won't work with things like `:gt` which are created by `jquery` so `matchesSelector` cant' be used if that is part of the selector.  So the `pos` thing is for those edge cases.  The edge case code uses context as documented, the simple case (browser supported selector) doesn't

Comment: But `matchesSelector` just does `matchesSelector(element, selector)` and returns true if the element passed in can be matched by the selector, there's no context used there, neither from the original collection, nor the one passed to `closest(selector, context)`, so if `pos` is `0` the context is just skipped. Depending on how you look at it, they either need to figure out a way to pass context to `matchesSelector`, or set `pos` correctly on just about any context other than `window`, so I agree, the issue could be fixed at that point as well.

Comment: @adeneo Yup, I think we're on the same page.  Thanks.  I thought it was broken but needed someone to bounce it off of.  Your answer (and discussion) were very helpful.  I'll submit a bug report.  They either need to change the documentation and remove this.context from pos, or make the non-pos version use this.context too.

Comment: Yes, this surely can't be what they intended. I do see that they have extended the regex for `pos` somewhere between 1.7 and 1.8 to match more cases, but it still has the same issues ?

Comment: @adeneo Was attempting to modify Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!=”value”] selector recently , had to remove `"^"` at beginning of `RegExp` for `"ATTR"` at line 712. `needsContext` of `rneedsContext` appear to be at line 720 . Not certain how to access , change `matchExpr` , tried thus far using  `$.expr` , though `matchExpr` regexps not extended from `Sizzle` ?

Comment: @guest271314 - `rneedsContext` is just an alias for `jQuery.expr.match.needsContext`, that's where the regex really is, but just changing the regex at runtime probably won't work as it's not passed by reference *(of a value)*, and it won't change all the places it's used etc.

Comment: @adeneo fwiw,  plnkr of deleted Question "How to extend, modify, or override jQuery Attribute Not Equal Selector [name!=”value”] selector?" http://plnkr.co/edit/uavSs1jcaMarbDKG1xfe . Was able to return expected result for `ul[class!='active']`, save for selector where space was within selector `body [class!='active']`. Also tried to create a `[data]` selector , similar to `[class]` or `[id]` , which would return all elements having `data-*` set at `html` or `jQuery.data()` . Documentation on how to adjust or extend selectors using `$.expr` appear sorely missing from jQuery documentation

Comment: Adjusted lines 713, 1699 at `script.js` at plnkr

Comment: @adeneo `.needsContext` does not appear to be extended to property of `$.expr.match` ? Try `$.expr.match` at `console`